# Arrow keys not working in input and textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple textarea and input in my webapplication. For some reason, I cannot go back in the typed text with the arrow keys. The input cursor does not move backwards.

I can however use ctrl+a, or click the with the mouse on the position that I want to edit. This is confusing. I am not using e.preventDefault in any key event in my code - having around 30 js files and some huge css files -.

Any ideas on why the arrows might not work?

Thanks!

Comment: Debug by removing certain JS files?

Comment: Can you provide a minimum working example? Some code?

Comment: First isolate the problem by removing succesive js files until arrow keys work again - than come back with the results.

Comment: @WTK Good point, I'll try to remove files on a dummy page until they work. I might start with the css first.

Comment: @Jleagle thanks, never thought of that, will try and come back with the result.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do a search in all your JS files and look for something similar to:

```
keyCode == 37
```

or

```
which == 37
```

as this is the left-arrow. Probably somewhere there is something similar to:

```
if (e.keyCode == 37)
   e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: that's it. After searching in the content of my js file I found that I had a dropdown menu component which was preventing the defaults of (33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40). Thanks!

Comment: I was skeptical when I first saw this answer.  Then I tried what you said.  Turns out you were right.  Mind blown.

Comment: this saved me a ton of time, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a comment to help people loading input and textareas inside a **lightbox**.
Most lightboxes bind the arrow keys to photo navigation (previous,next), so the arrow keys will not work in your form fields.

To fix that, just search the javascript code of your lightbox for the keycodes (as Jules suggested) and remove the code block that binds the arrow keys. Or you can condition it.

For example, in right-lightbox.js the keybinding code is

```
var b=p.current,c=({27:"close",33:"prev",37:"prev",38:"prev",39:"next",40:"next",34:"next"})[a.keyCode];
```

27 is the escape key, so you can leave that there, and remove the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look up for stuff like:

```
@HostListener('keydown.arrowup', ['$event']) keyUp(event) {
```

or

```
@HostListener('keydown.arrowdown', ['$event']) keyUp(event) {
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36717068/ie11-not-able-to-navigate-within-textarea-using-arrow-keys#comment61019543_36717068), a good way of debugging this issue can be the Developer tool : select the textarea that is problematic (using ctrl + shift + C for instance) and go to the `Event listeners` tab.

I found the origin of the behaviour under the `keydown` category. As expected, it was a `e.preventDefault();` that I had somehow previously missed.