# IE11: Not able to navigate within Textarea using Arrow Keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a **textarea** field as below

```html
<textarea id="remarksid" name="remarks" title="Enter Remarks " maxlength="4000" class="form-control" ></textarea>
```

When Text is entered into the above field, Not able to navigate between the words using *Arrow Keys* and Keyboard functions(such as Copy, Paste) does not work in **IE11**

**Note**: Works fine in *Safari, Chrome* and *Firefox*

Is there a fix for the same in IE11?

Comment: You must have some JavaScript code that prevents that. Your runnable snippet does not reproduce the issue or give any hint.

Comment: As starting point, open the Developer Tools (F12), highlight the textarea in DOM pane and click on "Events" to see if you're lucky. Also, do a code search for "onkey..." handlers.

Comment: There's a common problem with IE, 
be careful that it is not put in compatibility mode IE7. (F12 and look at the compatibility mode)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález: U r Right.. Javascript function was preventing it in IE11. The function to exclude special characters was the one. $("#remarksid").attr("value",valueStr); I m excluding special char in "valueStr" and adding it to #remarksid value. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, I took the liberty to adapt your comment into an answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/75885838/8244247
It was super useful to me !